# Is $\{\{x\}\}$ a neighborhood base for any $x\in X$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Folland gives the definition of a neighborhood base as

> $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$, a **neighborhood base** for $\mathcal{T}$ at $x\in X$ is a family $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{T}$ such that
>
> - $x\in V$ for all $V\in \mathcal{N}$;
> - if $U\subset\mathcal{T}$ and $x\in U$, there exists $V\in \mathcal{N}$ such that $x\in V$ and $V\subset U$.

So for any $x\in X$, is $\{\{x\}\}$ a neighborhood base for $x$? It seems to satisfy the requirements above.

If so, then I wonder whether the following highlighted sentence has problems:

[image]

If $x\in\partial A$, $\overline{A} \neq A$, and $U_j = \{x\}$ for any $j$, then is $U_j \cap A = \emptyset$ for any $j$ instead?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The neighborhood basis sets must be open!  (Note that your defn said $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{T}$.)  So, no, not generally, unless your space is discrete.

Comment: @Randall I see. Thanks! Then may I ask why the text highlighted in pink always holds?

Comment: If the conclulsion of that line were false, $x$ wouldn't be in the closure.  [Sometimes thinking contrapositive-ly is easier.]

Comment: That is why you should always go to concrete examples when studying topology. One example of a neighborhood base for ordinary Euclidean metric-induced topology on, say, $\mathbb R^n$ around a point $x\in\mathbb R^n$ is, simply, the set of all open balls (with radii $>0$) centred at $x$. This does _not_ include the 1-element set $\{x\}$. You can have a smaller (countable) neighborhood base by picking only radii in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Also $U_j\cap A=\emptyset$ is equivalent to $A\subseteq U_j^c$, but as the latter is _closed_ you have $\overline{A}\subseteq U_j^c$ i.e. $\overline A\cap U_j=\emptyset$, which with $x\in U_j$ implies $x\not\in\overline{A}$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Got it. Thank you for your clear answer and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement $\mathcal N \subset \mathcal T$ is what's important here. By saying $\{\{x\}\}=\mathcal N \subset \mathcal T$, you're saying $\{x\}$ is open for every $x\in X$. Therefore, this neighborhood base assignment is valid if and only if your space has the discrete topology.